# c:forEach - all list values with same value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I have a form with a table where I can add N person names to it, each time a button is pressed.

After submitting the form, I verified during debug that EACH time the setName() is called (for each inputText), ALL the names in the list are setted with that value - instead of just the name corresponding to the index.

An example:

[Example of the list values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsoH2.png)

The code is the following:

```
    <p:panelGrid>
      <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton id="addMoreFields" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" value="Add More Fields" actionListener="#{manageBean.addMoreFields()}" update="list" />
          </p:column>
      </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid id="list">
    <c:forEach items="#{manageBean.peopleList}" var="val" varStatus="loop">
      <p:panelGrid role="grid">
        <p:row>
          <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column>
            <p:inputText value="#{manageBean.myList[loop.index].name}" />
          </p:column>
        </p:row>
      </p:panelGrid>
    </c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="submit" value="submit" actionListener="#{manageBean.submit}" />
```

**ManageBean**:

```
...
        public List<Person> getPeopleList() {
        return getCurrentYear().getTeam().getPeopleInTeam();
    }
```

**Team:**

```
...

    private final List<Person> peopleList= new ArrayList<Person>();

        public List<Person> getPeopleInTeam() {
        return peopleList;
    }
```

**Person:**

```
...

private String name;
private String address;

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}
```

**EDIT:** finally understood the cause, but not the why. Apparently the getter being INSIDE a getter is what's causing this problem. If I have a list of people in the manageBean, it works perfectly. However, the list is specific PER team.
Any idea how I could achieve this? How why is this happening?

Comment: you are in a c:foreach component which means will iterate your list with each value set on  var="val"   .What is myList  ? . It should be <p:inputText value="#{val.name}" /> instead of <p:inputText value="#{manageBean.myList[loop.index].name}" />  ?

Comment: Try without a PrimeFaces panelgrid, try with a plain jsf `h:inputText`... Does it work then? And you DO tag it uirepeat (which is absent) but DO NOT tag it jstl (wicht you use)... Please improve, investigate... And @UtaAlexandru: you can use the loop.index, as long as you do it right, not real need to explicitly use the var (sometimes you even cant)

Comment: you can... but i do not think this is the case.he have a list of persons... name its in the Person object

Comment: That's why I said: _"as long as you do it right"_

Comment: @UtaAlexandru thanks for your reply! My first attempt was with  _<p:inputText value="#{val.name}" />_ as you suggested. Didn't work. That's when I tried some suggestions I found in my research. Any other thoughts/ideas? The problem persists...

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the reply and sorry for the tags mess up. I would tag both since I tried with both c:forEach and ui:repeat to reach a broader range of people, but there's a tag limit. I'll fix it. Regarding investigation... I've read pretty much every thread here regarding ui:repeat and c:forEach funcionality/problem. Can't find any scenario like mine: a getter calling another getter.

About the problem: plain h:inputText has the same behaviour. I'm open to suggestions. Could it be something about the getter calling another getter and inbetween the iteration is lost?
Thanks in advance.